# would using http.Get be slower than using curl in the exec.Command?

Tags: go

I have a program where I curl a web page, and then run a few commands on the output using exec.Command. Here is the code :

````
        cmd := `curl -s https://example.com | <some command 1> | <some command 2>`
        out, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", cmd).Output()```
````

Would using `resp, err := http.Get("https://example.com")` in Go, instead of using curl, and then sending the response body to exec.Command be any slower?

I ask this because, by using http.Get, the output is sent from the Go program, to the OS, which then performs operations on the output, and then sends it back to the Go program. There is supposed to be a performance hit, right?

Comment: With curl, you have to first exec curl, which is another program, that does the equivalent of http.Get. So in general, http.Get is what you should do.

Comment: It's not as if curl gets to skip any of that; it's just a program, same as your Go program. Calling curl to make a web request should be slower than making a web request directly. Calling bash to call curl (as you're doing in your example) should be even slower still.

Comment: Ideally you would use `io.Copy` on `exec.Cmd.Stdin` and `exec.Cmd.Stdout`, executing `some command 1` and `some command 2` separately so you don't have to get a shell (i.e `bash`) involved, and get more visibility on each command.

Comment: Hmm, if you're just calling some external programs you might as well just write a shell script...

Answer (score 1):

Exactly!

In addition to the socket send system calls, there is additional overhead from creating [an external process](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#StartProcess) and communicating between it:

https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go?s=6250:6295#L416

This would significantly change the performance and resource usage of your application because your application requires os level processes.  Consider the case where a client executed the `exec.Command` based implementation 100 times, 100 os level processes would be required in order to allow this.

But on the other hand consider the case where you use the http library directly, the system calls all stay within gos process space.

It should be pretty easy to create a benchmark with a local API to show the overhead of these `exec.Command` calls, and also go provides `pprof` which would allow you to profile at a much lower level to show you the overhead involved with the `exec.Command` calls.